# Error running 'npm install -g firebase-tools'

Tags: flutter, firebase

I ran the following code on the terminal to instal firebase-tools

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

I am trying to install this to use cloud functions on firebase and I got these errors:

```
juan@juans-Air ~ % npm install -g firebase-tools
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.firebase-tools-ENG41nb9
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.firebase-tools-ENG41nb9'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.firebase-tools-ENG41nb9'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.firebase-tools-ENG41nb9'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/juan/.npm/_logs/2022-10-30T02_59_24_185Z-debug-0.log
juan@juans-Air ~ %
```

Is there a different way to install this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ran it with sudo and it worked::

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```